# Uncaught SyntaxError in javascript function

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

I am trying to use the below function in my code which is running in cordova android application but getting syntax error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" which pointing at:

```
[src, gainNode, dst].reduce((a, b) => a && a.connect(b));
```

Here is a function:

```
function modifyGain (stream, gainValue){

var audioTrack = stream.getAudioTracks()[0];
var ctx = new AudioContext();
var src = ctx.createMediaStreamSource(new MediaStream([audioTrack]));
var dst = ctx.createMediaStreamDestination();
var gainNode = ctx.createGain();
gainNode.gain.value = gainValue;
[src, gainNode, dst].reduce((a, b) => a && a.connect(b)); // syntax error on this line
stream.removeTrack(audioTrack);
stream.addTrack(dst.stream.getAudioTracks()[0]);

};
```

Here is my browser info:

```
5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.4; D5503 Build/14.4.A.0.108) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Crosswalk/15.44.384.12 Mobile Safari/537.36
```

It is working fine on chrome 51 on my mac but give syntax error in android phone. Can someone tell me a reason and how i can simplyfy this rather than using expression.

Comment: And what does that line do, it's not returning the result anywhere, and the statement inside reduce returns a boolean on each iteration, which I'm guessing doesn't have a `connect` ?

Comment: Try to check supporting arrow functions on chrome 44 (or what browser gives you error)

Comment: Arrow notation is probably not supported in the version of the mobile browser you're using, [look here](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/). Look for _arrow functions_ on that page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try writing this line of code in ES5 syntax

```
[src, gainNode, dst].reduce( function(a, b) { return a && a.connect(b) });
```